# Which verbs can come with Vていただけませんか and Vていただきたい?

Tags: politeness, reading-comprehension, giving-and-receiving

There is somewhat [similar question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/52138/whats-the-difference-between-%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E3%81%8B-%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B-%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%8D%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84-%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99), but mine is not about the degrees of politeness.

As far as I understand, Vていただけませんか literally means something like “would I be able to get V from you?”. So, it's used with verbs when the speaker is the receiver of the verb's action: 教える, 貸す, etc.

And then, there is an exercise:

> すみません、ちょっと聞いて（＿）ことがあるんですが

with the choice between　⭕️いただきたい and ❌いただける.

Why is いただきたい is used here? Wouldn't it mean literally “I want to receive a question”?
Can, for example, 借りる be used similarly with たい form? Can these verbs be used with Vていただけませんか?

Comment: Have you learned how もらう works as a helper verb?

Comment: More or less, I think.

Comment: Then do you think 聞いてもらいたいことがある is also strange?

Comment: Yes, I do. If I had never seen this particular combination, I'd assume it would be ちょっと教えてもらいたいことがあるんです。

Comment: Only naruto's answer seems to understand that your fundamental problem is assuming the 'ask' meaning of 聞く here rather than 'listen'

Comment: @Angelos - I assumed the OP was thinking the main verb itself has to have a directional sense with something or some information moving from the listener (doer) to the speaker (like 教える and 貸す) for it to be used with もらう or いただく.

Answer (score 3):

A very literal translation of this is:

> 聞いていただきたいことがある
>
> There is something to which I want to (humbly) receive the favor of (your) listening.

聞いて (te-form of 聞く) refers to the listener's action (hence "*your* listening"), and this action is what the speaker wants to "receive". いただく (which is a humble version of もらう) refers to the speaker's action of receiving (the favor). It's directly followed by たい, making it "I want to receive".

A little more natural version of this sentence in English would be "There's something I want you to (kindly) listen to". An even simpler version would be "There's something I want to discuss with you".

I understand that it can be confusing at first, but this is a basic usage of the `te-form + もらう` construction, so please read your textbook and practice until you become comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

It's the helper verb いただく (or もらう in neutral language) that puts the speaker on the receiving end, not the main verb. The main verb can be anything as long as it refers to an action by someone else, including the listener, that the speaker sees as a favor or service for them and therefore appreciates. In the sentence of the exercise, the listener's action of listening to what the speaker has to say would be a service of which the speaker is on the receiving end. In more practical terms, いただく or もらう as a helper verb adds a sense of gratitude to the main verb.